# Conditional Awk hashmap match lookup

Tags: linux, perl, bash, unix, awk

I have 2 tabular files. One file contains a mapping of 50 key values only called **lookup_file.txt.**
The other file has the actual tabular data with 30 columns and millions of rows. **data.txt**
I would like to replace the id column of the second file with the values from the **lookup_file.txt.**.

How can I do this? I would prefer using awk in bash script..
Also, Is there a hashmap data-structure i can use in bash for storing the 50 key/values rather than another file?

Comment: you can use declare -A dict as dictionary in bash, and assign the values like dict=( ["key"]="value" )

Comment: It might be easier to import into sqlite, join, and export rather than writing a whole lot of bash, grep, sed and awk.

Comment: trival to use awk to load lookup_file.txt as an assoc array, then read thru data.txt replacing as needed. Don't have time now, others will show the way. Good luck to all.

Comment: The millions of rows makes this an interesting problem. Maybe you could give us some sample data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your files have comma-separated fields and the "id column" is field 3:

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
{ $3 = map[$3]; print }
' lookup_file.txt data.txt
```

If any of those assumptions are wrong, clue us in if the fix isn't obvious...

EDIT: and if you want to avoid the (IMHO negligible) NR==FNR test performance impact, this would be one of those every rare cases when use of getline is appropriate:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
   FS=OFS=","
   while ( (getline line < "lookup_file.txt") > 0 ) {
      split(line,f)
      map[f[1]] = f[2]
   }
}
{ $3 = map[$3]; print }
' data.txt
```

Comment: **+1**.  This is the only sane way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a mix of "sort" and "join" via bash instead of having to write it in awk/sed and it is likely to be even faster:

key.cvs (id, name)

```
1,homer
2,marge
3,bart
4,lisa
5,maggie
```

data.cvs (name,animal,owner,age)

```
snowball,dog,3,1
frosty,yeti,1,245
cujo,dog,5,4
```

Now, you need to sort both files first on the user id columns:

```
cat key.cvs | sort -t, -k1,1 > sorted_keys.cvs
cat data.cvs | sort -t, -k3,3 > sorted_data.cvs
```

Now join the 2 files:

```
join -1 1 -2 3 -o "2.1 2.2 1.2 2.4" -t , sorted_keys.cvs sorted_data.cvs > replaced_data.cvs
```

This should produce:

```
snowball,dog,bart,1
frosty,yeti,homer,245
cujo,dog,maggie,4
```

This:

```
-o "2.1 2.2 1.2 2.4"
```

Is saying what columns from the 2 files you want in your final output.

It is pretty fast for finding and replacing multiple gigs of data compared to other scripting languages.  I haven't done a direct comparison to SED/AWK, but it is much easier to write a bash script wrapping this than writing in SED/AWK (for me at least).

Also, you can speed up the sort by using an upgraded version of gnu coreutils so that you can do the sort in parallel

```
cat data.cvs | sort --parallel=4 -t, -k3,3 > sorted_data.cvs
```

4 being how many threads you want to run it in. I was recommended 2 threads per machine core will usually max out the machine, but if it is dedicated just for this, that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. But if you want an easy one liner, without much in the way of validation I would go with an awk/sed solution.

Assume the following:

1. the files are tab delimited
2. you are using bash shell
3. the id in the data file is in the first column
4. your files look like this:

### lookup

```
1   one
2   two
3   three
4   four
5   five
```

### data

```
1   col2    col3    col4    col5
2   col2    col3    col4    col5
3   col2    col3    col4    col5
4   col2    col3    col4    col5
5   col2    col3    col4    col5
```

I would use `awk` and `sed` to accomplish this task like this:

```
awk '{print "sed -i s/^"$1"/"$2"/ data"}' lookup | bash
```

what this is doing is going through each line of lookup and writing the following to stdout

`sed -i s/^1/one/ data`

`sed -i s/^2/two/ data`

and so on.

it next pipes each line to the shell (`| bash`), which will execute the `sed` expression. -i for inplace, you may want `-i.bak` to create a backup file. note you can change the extension to whatever you would like. 
the sed is looking for the id at the start of the line, as indicated by the `^`. You don't want to be replacing an 'id' in a column that might not contain an id.

your output would look like the following:

```
one     col2    col3    col4    col5
two     col2    col3    col4    col5
three   col2    col3    col4    col5
four    col2    col3    col4    col5
five    col2    col3    col4    col5
```

of course, your ids are probably not simply 1 to one, 2 to two, etc, but this might get you started in the right direction. And I use the term right very loosely.

Comment: This would invoke sed once for every row in the "millions of rows" the OP mentioned, creating a temp file each time, editing it and copying that back to the original. It would take a very, very long time to run.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this is to use `awk` to write an `awk` program to process the larger file:

```
awk -f <(awk '
   BEGIN{print " BEGIN{"}
        {printf "      a[\"%s\"]=\"%s\";",$1,$2}
   END  {print "      }";
         print "      {$1=a[$1];print $0}"}
   ' lookup_file.txt
) data.txt
```

That assumes that the `id` column is column 1; if not, you need to change both instances of `$1` in `$1=a[$1]`

Comment: why would you do it that way instead of just doing it in one awk script? If you want to avoid the NR==FNR test performance impact (not worth avoiding IMHO) you could just read lookup_file.txt into an array with a getline loop in the BEGIN section.

Comment: @EdMorton If it's one-shot, maybe it's not worth it, but most of the time it will prove useful to have the translation script kicking around without having to regenerate it. That makes it much easier to, for example, work on segments of the big file. In practice, I would probably make the last line of the generated script `{$1=a[$1]}` so that I can append processing with `--source` on the command line.